# Forced transparent border on a div of pictures?

Tags: css, wordpress, overlay, transparency, transparent

I have a `div` containing pictures that will be updated frequently on WordPress.  I would like to avoid having to edit the border of each image. This is kind of a dome-shaped border around a group of 8 photos that I created by using the clipping mask on Photoshop.

Is there a CSS trick I can use to make the `border.png` file overlay the `div` with the pictures and become transparent and block out the areas that it covers on the picture `div`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `border: none` will remove the border, but also will remove the artificial "padding" from the width of that border. If you want the spacing to stay the same, you can do `border-color: transparent`. Note, however, that [IE6 and earlier](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-color.asp) do not support border-color's transparent property.

Comment: `transparent` works, except on ancient IE6-7, but it might be fixable with IE filters if necessary.

Comment: Are you sure? I've seen it work in IE7, though I know for a fact IE 6 and earlier don't support it. I suppose it only really matters if the OP is expecting users to be using those older browsers -- eg. corporate users.

Comment: Well, it might be only IE6, who remembers these ancient details :)

Comment: We poor and unfortunate souls who are given complex designs and told that we must "support IE 5.5 and higher." :-/

Comment: Magic Pink can help on IE6: http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/emulating-border-color-transparent-in-internet-explorer-6/

Comment: Super late, but thank you!  I put this project off but finally started again :)